# Python3 exchangelib connect error: _ssl.c:749?

Tags: python, ssl

Python3 exchangelib connect error: _ssl.c:749?

I am trying to connect to my company's Exchange server with exchangelib.
I want to see all the mails I have received on MS Exchange / OWA.

When I run the code below, I get:

```
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 850, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 326, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 329, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\ssl.py", line 401, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\ssl.py", line 808, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\ssl.py", line 1061, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\ssl.py", line 683, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)






from exchangelib import DELEGATE, Account, Credentials,NTLM,Configuration,Version,Build
creds = Credentials(username = 'inter.com\\login',password='password')
config = Configuration(service_endpoint='https://alpha.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx',credentials=creds,auth_type=NTLM)
account = Account(primary_smtp_address='login@alpha.com',config=config,autodiscover=False,access_type=DELEGATE,verify_ssl=False)
from exchangelib.protocol import BaseProtocol, NoVerifyHTTPAdapter
BaseProtocol.HTTP_ADAPTER_CLS = NoVerifyHTTPAdapter
```

Can you please let me know how to use certificates with exchangelib?

How to fix it?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried disabling ssl verification in your config ?

```
config = Configuration(service_endpoint ='...', credentials=credentials, auth_type=NTLM, verify_ssl=False)
```

The [sources](https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/blob/master/scripts/optimize.py) seem to talk about a parameter like this.

Comment: in my code I wrote:
from exchangelib.protocol import BaseProtocol, NoVerifyHTTPAdapter
BaseProtocol.HTTP_ADAPTER_CLS = NoVerifyHTTPAdapter

Comment: oversaw that. Do you have tried to put the _NoVerifyHTTPAdapter_ statement before calling _exchangelib, creds & Account()_